# Why does the graph of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1$ not touch either of the axes?

Tags: graphing-functions

I entered this function on a graphing calculator and found that it did not touch either axes. Can someone please explain why x,y cannot be zero?

Comment: Can you add the picture to your post? Because it should "touch" the axes at $x=1,y=0$ and $x=0,y=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation translates to $ \sqrt{y} = 1-\sqrt{x} $ and $ y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2 $ for $x>0$

Now try to solve your equation for $y=0$ :
$$0=(1-\sqrt{x})^2 $$
$$0=1-\sqrt{x} $$
$$1 = \sqrt{x} $$
$$x=1$$
and vice versa. So you have to points $(0|1)$ and $(1|0)$ touching the axes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the graph.  Of course the function goes through both $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which graphics calculator are you using I plotted it using Desmos and it touches the axis at points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$

[image]